# How can i change resource folder(.yml)

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml, profile

i want to change resource folder .yml by doing add option '-Pprofile=' at build

so

i know that in CLI

1. gradle clean -Pprofile=env1 bootJar
2. java -jar build/libs/myProject.jar

- build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
  ext.profile = (!project.hasProperty('profile') || !profile ) ? 'env1' : profile

  main {
    resources {
      srcDirs "src/main/resources-env/${profile}"
    }
  }
}
```

but how can i add build option '-Pprofile=' in Run/debug configurations Application(in intellij build not gradle)

i thought adding -Pprofile option in Program arguments,
intellij rebuild project and change resource folder in 'out'

but intellij doesn't rebuild and just run

i want to build intellij not gradle

how can i do that?

plz helt

Comment: Please make the context of your question clearer in the title. Also, I suggest you clarify what you mean with "I want to build intellij": Do you want to build intellij, or do you want to build *through* intellij?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating a [Gradle Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#gradle_run_config).

You can supply `-P` argument in the Run field:

[image: Gradle Run Configuration Sample]